# Connection factory shut down after several failback

Tags: jboss, high-availability, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

I have a JBoss cluster with two nodes in HA shared store mode.

When I kill the live node 1, backup node 2 become the live one.

When I restart node 1, thanks to failback, node 1 become the live server, and node 2 become, again, the backup server.

But, when I kill again the node 1, node 2 become the live server, but I get the following exception:

```
10:38:46,545 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyManager] (Camel (camel-poc) thread #20 - TemporaryQueueReplyManager[MY_QUEUE]) Exception inside the DMLC for Temporary ReplyTo Queue for destination MY_QUEUE, refreshing ReplyTo destination: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create a session: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:/JmsXA
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.allocateConnection(ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:895)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:520)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:192)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.access$1400(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:124)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000470: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been shut down: java:/JmsXA
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:735)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.allocateConnection(ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:853)
        ... 8 more
```

And of course, I cannot use this queue anymore.

Here is my messaging subsystem definition (basically the same as defined in standalone-ha configuration) :

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:admin123!}"/>
            <management jmx-enabled="true"/>
            <statistics enabled="true"/>
            <shared-store-slave allow-failback="true"/>
            <bindings-directory path="D:\dev\tools\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-7.0.0-ha\shared_jboss\bindings"/>
            <journal-directory path="D:\dev\tools\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-7.0.0-ha\shared_jboss\journal"/>
            <large-messages-directory path="D:\dev\tools\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-7.0.0-ha\shared_jboss\largemessages"/>
            <paging-directory path="D:\dev\tools\jboss-eap\jboss-eap-7.0.0-ha\shared_jboss\paging"/>
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" redistribution-delay="1000" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" connectors="http-connector" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
            <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" discovery-group="dg-group1" connector-name="http-connector" address="jms"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="MY_QUEUE" entries="java:/jms/queue/MY_QUEUE"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" reconnect-attempts="-1" block-on-acknowledge="true" ha="true" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

Is it a normal behavior or something is misconfigured?

**EDIT:**

The consumer is deployed on the live server and on the backup server. The queue is used in a Camel context and its defined in the context as follow:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    jndi-name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://cxf.apache.org/wsse/handler/hell"
    trace="true" id="camel-jms-queue">
    <route id="wsProxyRedirection">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:cdcPocProxyWebServiceStartPoint" />
        <to uri="jms:queue:MY_QUEUE" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Where is the consumer running?  Is it running on the live, back-up, or a 3rd node?

Comment: I edited my question with more informations

Comment: I think one of the more common causes of this error is a case where some code caches a reference to ("java:/JmsXA") instead of looking it up (each time it is needed to obtain connections) in JNDI. There are cases where a pool will be invalidated (e.g. when reconfiguring the pool via a management interface, when explicitly flushing the pool via a management interface, when connections are invalidated or timed out and the pool population drops to zero, etc.). Consequently, caching of JNDI references is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

> The consumer is deployed on the live server and on the backup server.

Deploying an application on a server where the broker will be activated and deactivated during the normal course of operation (as is the case for a live/backup pair) is not recommended.  Instead it is recommended that you configure your live/backup pair and host the application on a 3rd server that will remotely connect to the live/backup pair using the appropriate HA configuration which will enable fail-over (i.e. ha=true).

In your current situation the whole broker (as well as the associated queues, connection factories, etc.) are being deployed and undeployed which is almost certainly not something the Spring components can understand and/or deal with gracefully.

Comment: Why should it be a problem if the server is restarted (with the deployment embedded)? Creating a thrid and a fourth server (for HA) will be performance consuming..